# Minikube has IP - Can't Curl

Tags: docker, curl, kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-ingress

Minikube is up and running, with no errors, but I can't curl the IP. I'm following along here: https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/, and there seems to be no mention of turning off a firewall or setting a config to allow minikube to listen on the IP. What is going on?

```
patientplatypus:~/Documents/HomePage:15:57:04$minikube ip
192.168.99.114
patientplatypus:~/Documents/HomePage:15:57:10$curl $(minikube ip)
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.114 port 80: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked if it is really running on port 80? Probably is a wrong port or a firewall rule on machine 192.168.99.114. You can try nmap to verify which ports are open on this machine.

Comment: Minikube now apparently no longer supports using port 80, only port 8443 (https). Which is a bummer as it means some of the examples I was using are broken (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54699441/traefik-examples-broken-cant-curl-minikube). But this was definitely the answer to this sub question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PeterWeyand your link is broken