# Creating Services. curl timed out when doing curl http://$(minikube ip):32000

Tags: kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, docker-desktop

(WSL2, minikube, Windows 11, Calico plugin, Docker-Desktop)

I simply don't understand why curl timed out when doing `curl http://$(minikube ip):32000`.
I saw [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54699742/minikube-has-ip-cant-curl) but they are not applicable.

```
$ k create deploy nginxsvc --image=nginx --replicas=3
$ k expose deploy nginxsvc --port=80
```

Then I edited the service to change Service Type to NodePort.

```
$ k get svc
NAME TYPE CLUSTER-IP EXTERNAL-IP PORT(S) AGE
kubernetes ClusterIP 10.96.0.1 <none> 443/TCP 18d
nginxsvc NodePort 10.103.11.225 <none> 80:32000/TCP 19m
regular-encourager NodePort 10.102.236.129 <none> 8080:32058/TCP 15d

$ curl http://$(minikube ip):32000
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 192.168.49.2 port 32000: Connection timed out

$ k describe svc nginxsvc

Name: nginxsvc

Namespace: default

Labels: app=nginxsvc

Annotations: <none>

Selector: app=nginxsvc

Type: NodePort

IP Family Policy: SingleStack

IP Families: IPv4

IP: 10.103.11.225

IPs: 10.103.11.225

Port: <unset> 80/TCP

TargetPort: 80/TCP

NodePort: <unset> 32000/TCP

Endpoints: 10.244.1.233:80,10.244.1.234:80,10.244.1.235:80

Session Affinity: None

External Traffic Policy: Cluster

Events: <none>

$ k get svc nginxsvc -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-03-28T23:18:04Z"
  labels:
    app: nginxsvc
  name: nginxsvc
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "531373"
  uid: fcd7960e-8610-4099-a014-9b4ce94cdec2
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.103.11.225
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.103.11.225
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - nodePort: 32000
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginxsvc
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: *The network is limited if using the Docker driver on Darwin, Windows, or WSL, and the Node IP is not reachable directly.*

Take a look here: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#using-minikube-service-with-tunnel

Comment: @glv from your link, it says, "If you are using Docker driver on Windows, there is a chance that you have an old version of SSH client". That issue refers to ssh v7.7. I have v8.6 ssh.

Comment: @glv your link is for "Using minikube service with tunnel". I am not using a tunnel here, AFAIK.

Comment: Can you check this link below that might have the same scenario that you have.

https://forums.docker.com/t/curl-or-telnet-timed-out-when-access-a-docker-network-interface/134174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @glv pointed [out](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#using-minikube-service-with-tunnel),

> The network is limited if using the Docker driver on Darwin, Windows,
> or WSL, and the Node IP is not reachable directly.

The solution was to

1. remove minikube from WSL

   minikube delete --purge
2. Then installed VirtualBox on Windows
3. Install Ubuntu
4. Install docker then minikube, kubectl on Ubuntu
5. Start minikube

   minikube start --memory=6g --cpus=4 --driver=docker --cni=calico

Now all the networking that earlier failed, is now working!

Answer (score 0):

Run service tunnel

minikube service nginxsvc --url

minikube service nginxsvc --url runs as a process, creating a tunnel to the cluster. The command exposes the service directly to any program running on the host operating system.

Because you are using a Docker driver on linux, the terminal needs to be open to run the exposed service url (e.g., http://127.0.0.1:32897) in a browser

or

Open a new terminal and run

curl 127.0.0.1:32897

You should get the output of the service